# gigya ~ Comments plugin ~ default templates?

Tags: templates, gigya

According to the gigya [Comments plugin developer documentation](http://developers.gigya.com/010_Developer_Guide/18_Plugins/020_The_Comments_Plugin#Templates)..

> A template is a layout definition for a group of related graphics
>   elements in the plugin. The plugin includes five customizable
>   templates. You may assign each template with an HTML string that
>   redefines its graphic layout.  The 'templates' parameter of the
>   socialize.showCommentsUI method receives an object with the following
>   fields:
>
> - comment
> - commentBox
> - loginCanvas_loggedIn
> - loginCanvas_loggedIn_guest
> - loginCanvas_loggedOut
>
> Each of the fields is
>   a customizable template. **Each field has a default value that you may
>   override**. In the following ...

What are the default values of those templates?

Answer (score 1):

as you can see in this example:

http://wikifiles.gigya.com/Socialize/CommentsUI_Example_Templates.htm

you just build html templates, assign them to a json object and pass them to the gigya comments function as part of the params:

```
var templates = {

    commentBox: '<span style="color:blue;">This is the Login Canvas: </span><br>$loginCanvas<br><br>' +

                '<span style="color:blue;">This is the Close Icon: </span>$closeIcon<br>' +

                '<span style="color:blue;">This is the Add Comment text box: </span>$addComment',

    comment:'Hello!<br>' +

            '<span style="color:blue;">This is the username: </span>$username<br>' +

            '<span style="color:blue;">This is the Photo Div: </span>$photoDiv<br><br><br>' +

            '<span style="color:blue;">This is the Date String: </span>$dateString<br>' +

            '<span style="color:blue;">This is the Comment Body: </span>$body<br>' +

            '<span style="color:blue;">This is the Replies Count: </span>$repliesCountPlaceholder<br>' +

            '<span style="color:blue;">This is the Reply Button: </span>$replyButton<br><br>' +

            '<span style="color:blue;">This is the Flagging option: </span>$flag<br>' +

            '<span style="color:blue;">This is the Voting option: </span>$vote<br><br>',

    loginCanvas_loggedIn: '<span style="color:blue;">Login Canvas - Logged in state! </span><br>$photoDiv<br>$username<br>$logoutLink',

    loginCanvas_loggedIn_guest: '<span style="color:blue;">Login Canvas - Guest user state! </span><br>$photoDiv<br>$username<br>$logoutLink',

    loginCanvas_loggedOut: '<span style="color:blue;">Login Canvas - Logged Out state!<br></span>$photoDiv<br>$loginDropdown<br>$guestDropdown'

}



var params =

{

    // Required parameters:

    categoryID: 7623701,

    containerID: 'commentsDiv',



    // Optional parameters:

    templates: templates,

    streamID: 'foo6',

    cid: ''

}

// Load the Comments Plugin

gigya.socialize.showCommentsUI(params);
```